# Ubuntu search does not find .htaccess

Tags: search

I have a folder which has sub folders where some of them contain .htaccess files.

But if I use the search tool I do not find any of these files.

Also using in terminal:

```
find ~/web '.htaccess'
```

leaves me with nothing.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Using the tilde (`~`) means "your home folder". So you are looking for `.htaccess` into a sub-folder called `web` of your home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the dash does not search for hidden files for security reasons.

(Files starting with . (dot) are hidden files).

To search in a Terminal use -name

```
find ~/web -name '.htaccess'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **locate** function to search the entire system for .htaccess

`locate .htaccess`

Comment: Note that this command uses a kind of indexing database that is updated daily. So this is normal for this command to not return files that would have been copied the same day you run it.